# Does the addition of an adjective/attributive in front of a noun change its meaning? In what case?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives, attributives

> In 2006, Pluto was reclassified from a planet to a dwarf planet.

I'm sorry to ask, if this is a very basic question. Very confusing for my mind. Maybe I am dumb.

For instance, isn't a big ball still a ball? A long story is still a story. You can have a voracious cat—that's fine, it still remains a cat. It does not become a dog or a hamster etc.

So, if we consider the Pluto's status change, does the addition of an adjective or an attributive change the meaning of the respective noun? In which cases?

Comment: Generally, yes, a big ball is still a ball.  But in this case the words are being used as classifications with specific meanings.  See eg http://www.differencebetween.net/science/difference-between-dwarf-planet-and-planet/

Comment: It does here and often in government; consider that "budget cut" means "a lowering of the rate of increase in spending". It is not an actual cut at all. :)

Comment: In your language, isn't a big dog different from a little dog? Come on....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, adding an adjective means that the thing is now some special case or sub-type of the general word. Like yes, a "big ball" is a kind of "ball". It's still a ball.

But something the combination adjective-noun means something different from the simple noun. To take an obvious example, if I say that something is "counterfeit money", it's not really "money" any more, it's something that someone is pretending is money. Or if I say someone is a "former girlfriend", she's not my girlfriend any more. This is especially true with names for things. A "Tasmanian tiger" is not a sub-type of "tiger", it's a different creature that happens to resemble a tiger. A "flying boat" is not a kind of boat, its a type of aircraft that is compared to a boat in some ways. Etc.

I don't think there's any general rule about this. You just have to know what the particular words and phrases mean.